# LINQ filter list and exclude MAX value

Tags: c#, linq

New to LINQ and trying to figure out how to exclude an item from a list.  I have a list of names and their position level.  Which looks like

```
Name    ID    Level
aaa     123   0
bbb     122   1
ccc     222   2
ddd     223   3
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out a way to exclude the record with the highest level.  I'm refactoring some code that was using a for loop to check for this and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to mirror that.

Comment: Are all `Level` values different and unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact structure of your types is not clear, but something like this:

`list.OrderBy(x=>x.Level).Take(list.Count-1)` //where `x` is an Item (Raw) from he list

should work foryou.

if you might have *multiple MAX* values just use [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (see examples in documentation how to use it)

if you might have multiple repetitive values in collection (including non MAX values), you might do

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Level);
var max = list.First();
var result = list.SkipWhile(x=>x == max);
```

Comment: Did you originally post:

    list.OrderBy(x => x.Level).Take(list.Count - 1).ToList();

because that worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild: you on't need `ToList()`if you intend to siply iterate over result.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```
var max = list
    .Max(l => l.Level);

var listWithoutMax = list
    .Where(l => l.Level != max);
```

Answer (score 1):

This small code snippet should work fine:

```
Int32 max = list.Max(x => x.Level);
List<MyObject> newList = list.Where(x => x.Level != max).ToList();
```

and, if your list contains more than one element with the maximum level value, will ensure that all of them will be removed from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RemoveAll()`:

```
var result = list.RemoveAll(x => x.Level == list.Max(s => s.Level));
```